# creating phonebook without struct

Tags: c

I need some help,my project is to make a phone book:

*First option :add contact*

*Second option : display contacts*

My problem is , when i tried to add more the one contact when i press "display contacts " he show me only the last one i added .
i will share my code:

```
    int selection;
    char name2[20], last2[20];
    int number1[10],i,count=0;

    scanf_s("%d", &selection);
    while (selection != 5) {
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:

               AddContact();
               break;
        case 2:
                DisplayContact();
                printf("============================== \n");
                break;
    void AddContact()
    {
        int i;
        char name[21], last[21];
        int number[11];

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf_s("%s",name);
        printf("Enter  last name: ");
        scanf_s("%s", last);
        printf("Enter mobile number: ");
        scanf_s("%d",number);
        printf("CONTACT ADDED\n");
    }
    void DisplayContact()
    {
        int i;
        char name[21], last[21];
        int number[11];
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("Contact ID    : %d\n",i+1 );
            printf("Name  : %s %s\n", name, last);
            printf("Mobile: %d\n", number);
            printf("\n");
         }
```

Comment: It's an unreliable coincidence that you even get the last one you entered -- it only appears to do that because coincidentally the arrays in `DisplayContact` are probably using the same memory as the no-longer-valid-at-that-point arrays from `AddContact` were (not guaranteed at all).

Comment: If you want to save a list of contacts, you'll need somewhere to save them to... separate storage for each contact, and it must persist and be accessible to all the functions that need to access it (by passing pointers for example).  Right now you're only using temporary local variables in each function that don't even remain valid when the function returns.

Comment: _Without struct_??? Why? This problem cries out for a `struct`. An _array_ of structs. Is this some [goofy] requirement for an assignment? Or, are you just unfamiliar with when/how to use a struct?

Comment: i really dont know how to use struct ..

Answer (score 1):

All of your variables are *function* scope. They have nothing when you enter a function and go away when you leave

You need the data to *persist*, so you need to use global scope variables.

And, as I mentioned above, using a `struct` makes things easier.

Also, since the prompting is similar for each field, I've added a common function.

Here's a refactored version of your code that uses a `struct` [with a `typedef`] and implements the basic functionality:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRMAX  100
typedef struct {
    char name[STRMAX];
    char last[STRMAX];
    char number[STRMAX];
} contact_t;

int size;
#define CONMAX  20
contact_t contacts[CONMAX];

void
prompt(char *str,const char *what)
{

    printf("Enter %s: ",what);
    scanf(" %99s",str);
}

void
AddContact(void)
{
    contact_t *con;

    if ((size + 1) >= CONMAX) {
        printf("too many contacts\n");
        return;
    }

    con = &contacts[size];

    prompt(con->name,"name");
    prompt(con->last,"last name");
    prompt(con->number,"mobile number");

    printf("CONTACT ADDED\n");

    ++size;
}

void
DisplayContact(void)
{
    contact_t *con;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        con = &contacts[i];
        printf("Contact ID    : %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Name  : %s %s\n", con->name, con->last);
        printf("Mobile: %d\n", con->number);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    int selection;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter (1=add, 2=display): ");
        scanf(" %d", &selection);

        if (selection == 5)
            break;

        switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            AddContact();
            break;

        case 2:
            DisplayContact();
            printf("============================== \n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("Unknown: %d\n",selection);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```